# Largest palindrome as the product of two three-digit numbers with R

Tags: r

My assignment was to write a function that checks if a number is a palindrome, then to check that the function works with a palindromic number and a non-palindromic number. My next task was to find the largest palindromic number that is the product of two three-digit numbers and the two numbers that form it. To do this, the instructions require me to use two for loops, with one nested inside of the other. I successfully accomplished most of this task using some of the JavaScript examples on this website, and was able to output the largest palindrome using two three-digit numbers. However, I cannot figure out how to output the two numbers that, when multiplied together, obtain this palindrome. May someone point me in the right direction?

```
isPalindrome <- function(x) {
    return(x == paste(rev(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), split = ''))), collapse = ''))
}

isPalindrome(11223344332211)
[1] TRUE
isPalindrome(34631111113185)
[1] FALSE

max <- 100001
for(x in 999:100) {
  for(y in 999:x) {
    product <- x * y
    if(max < product && (isPalindrome(product) == TRUE)) {
      max <- product
    }
  }
}
cat(max)
906609
```

I know the two numbers are 993 and 913 based on my reading, but cannot figure out how to output them. For instance, when I type the following, I see the two answers, but am getting 924 and 962 as part of the output.

```
max <- 100001
for(x in 999:100) {
  for(y in 999:x) {
    product <- x * y
    if(max < product && (isPalindrome(product) == TRUE)) {
      max <- product
      cat(x, y)
    }
  }
}
924 962913 993> cat(max)
906609
```

Thanks!

Comment: Checking things one-at-a-time is fine for most languages, but if you want a pointer to a more R-like way of doing things, try `candidates = expand.grid(x = 100:999, y = 100:999)`, `candidates = subset(candidates, x <= y)`, `candidates$product = candidates$x * candidates$y`. With a little adjustment you could vectorize your `isPalindrome` function and do it all in one go.

Comment: @Gregor not in this case, `isPalindrome` is the most expensive function but he is only using it on a tiny fraction of possibilities (a few thousand) whereas doing it all in one go would check hundreds of thousands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the correct answer.  Hint: you're function is finding two pairs of values:

Try this:

```
max <- 100001
for(x in 999:100) {
  for(y in 999:x) {
    product <- x * y
    if(max < product && (isPalindrome(product) == TRUE)) {
      max <- product
      cat(x, y, "\n")
    }
  }
}
```